# UWP app errors when built in .Net Native

Tags: mvvm-light, win-universal-app

We've got a Windows 8.1 app that we've converted to a Windows 10 UWP app. The app works fine in debug, but when running in Release (.Net Native), we are getting a runtime error on app load. It's not at all clear what's causing the error. The error happens in the OnLaunched event in App.xaml.cs where some data is being initialized. The error:

> An exception of type System.NullReferenceException occurred in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>
> Additional information: Arg_NullReferenceException

We're using the latest versions of MVVM Light.

I know this isn't a lot of info, but it's really all we have right now and are pretty stumped. Anyone seen and issue like this or know where to start in tracking it down?

Comment: You need to be aware that .Net Native will try to optimize the references. So any type it thinks is not needed will be omitted. Hence, if there is any reflection going on in your code or in any referenced lib, you need to explicitly add that back in the rd.xml file. More info http://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html

Comment: Same problem here, I found out that the error was caused by the first call to Messenger.Default,Register<> method, I tried to add a directive for that, but still have that error :

`<Type Name="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger">
<MethodInstantiation Name="Register" Arguments="string" Dynamic="Required" />
</Type>
<Assembly Name="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll" Dynamic="Required All" />`

Any suggestions @Depechie ?

Comment: Sorry I'm no specialist on how to go through the .net native errors :/

Answer (score 0):

If, you're still using SQLite or any Reference.
Please Right Click to your `Project => Add => Reference => Make sure your DLL of Nuget` is checked.

Please Check this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem in that I converted an 8.1 app to UWP. This was resolved by including a file called `Default.rd.xml` in the `Properties` folder. This was not mentioned in the migration guide that I had used.

Not including it means some pretty common coding patterns such as reflection will not work, and this includes in imported .dll's.

A basic `Default.rd.xml` file looks like the following ...

```
<!--
    This file contains Runtime Directives used by .NET Native. The defaults here are suitable for most
    developers. However, you can modify these parameters to modify the behavior of the .NET Native
    optimizer.

    Runtime Directives are documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=391919

    To fully enable reflection for App1.MyClass and all of its public/private members
    <Type Name="App1.MyClass" Dynamic="Required All"/>

    To enable dynamic creation of the specific instantiation of AppClass<T> over System.Int32
    <TypeInstantiation Name="App1.AppClass" Arguments="System.Int32" Activate="Required Public" />

    Using the Namespace directive to apply reflection policy to all the types in a particular namespace
    <Namespace Name="DataClasses.ViewModels" Serialize="All" />
-->

<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
  <Application>
    <!--
      An Assembly element with Name="*Application*" applies to all assemblies in
      the application package. The asterisks are not wildcards.
    -->
    <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />


    <!-- Add your application specific runtime directives here. -->


  </Application>
</Directives>
```

If this does not work, then try creating a new empty UWP project to get the latest format for the file.